# HTML 'for' attribute target in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, translate

```
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_local_pickup7" value="local_pickup:7" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
        <label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup7">Self pickup</label>
</li>
```

How can I target this label in CSS stylesheet? i want to edit this level value by css.

Comment: `[for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup7"]` - Have you tried googling it?

Comment: Yes! it's woocommarce plugin issue. I need to translate 'Self Pickup' text. By default, I can't do this by loco translator plugin. So, i decide to do this manually. But 'for' attribute is making a problem.  I want to target this by CSS.

Comment: Justinas has shown you exactly how to do that. The duplicate question also has lots of examples. What is the problem?

Comment: _"i want to edit this [label] value by css"_ - You can not edit text with CSS.

Comment: {
content: 'edited new text';
}

if i try this, I hope i can.

Comment: @ArifulMowla `content:` works only for `:before` and `:after`

Comment: `content` only works on pseudo elements. The only way you could do this would be similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/w37L4q1b/2/ . I'm not sure why you would want to replace the text with CSS. This would usually be done using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! I was desperately seeking this. :)

Answer (score -3):

for is nothing but name attribute. you just target the name attribute in css that's it.

Comment: But i can't target the level. I need to target the level instead of input.

Comment: pls you cannot just ask any questions without elaboration. why is there "for" in the title too???

Comment: Please check this.
        <label for="shipping_method_0_local_pickup7">Self pickup</label>